# REST Framework — Serializing many-to-many. Create and Save

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, m2m

I am using django-restframework for my API.

My problems:  I can't validate data. Need to create "regions" and nested with courier. Regions send as a list in json.

But when validating the data, I get the following errors:
`error_valid {'regions': [{'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int.', code='invalid')]}, {'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int.', code='invalid')]}, {'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int.', code='invalid')]`

How I can created models with this json POST request?

The POST json:

```
{
"data": [
{
"courier_id": 10,
"courier_type": "foot",
"regions": [1, 12, 22]
},
{
"courier_id": 11,
"courier_type": "bike",
"regions": [22]
},..
]
}
```

My models.py:

```
class Regions(models.Model):
    region_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.region_id


class Courier(models.Model):
    courier_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True,
                                             )
    courier_type = models.CharField(max_length=4,
                                    choices=TypeCourier.choices,
                                    blank=False,
                                    )
    regions = models.ManyToManyField("Regions",
                                     through=RegionsCouriers,
                                     through_fields=("courier",
                                                     "region"
                                                     ),
                                     )
```

Regions will need to be created together with the post request
my serializers.py

```
class RegionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        fields = "__all__"
        model = Regions


class CourierSerializerPost(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    regions = RegionsSerrializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Courier
        fields = "__all__"
```

my View.py

```
class CourierView(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data["data"]
        couriers_add = []
        couriers_fail = []
        for record in data:
            serializer = CourierSerializerPost(data=record)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                courier_id = record["courier_id"]
                couriers_add.append({"id": courier_id})
                serializer.save()
            else:
                couriers_fail.append({"id": record["courier_id"]})
        if couriers_fail:
            return Response({"couriers": couriers_fail},
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return Response({"couriers": couriers_add},
                            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
                            )
```

Please, help me
UPD:
How i can change validate regions field as  a list positive integer field.
My error: i can't create:
`record {'courier_id': 12, 'courier_type': 'car', 'regions': [12, 22, 23, 33]}`

`serializer.is_valid False`

`serializer.error {'regions': [{'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int.', code='invalid')]},`

Answer (score 1):

you can't use a serializer to save M2M fields as you do with a Foreign key or one-to-one.

you need to override the serializer's create method and specify the M2M adding

```py
class CourierSerializerPost(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    regions = RegionsSerrializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Courier
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # removing the regions ids from the about to be created Courier obj
        regions_ids = validated_data.pop('regions', None)
        # getting the regions objs
        regions = tuple(Regions.objects.filter(id__in=regions_ids))
        # creating the Courier object
        obj = Courier.objects.create(**validated_data)
        # adding the regions relations to it
        obj.regions.add(*regions)
        return obj
```

Comment: Thanks for help, for the tip with method overriding  ), but i have this problem with validate( i can't create:
`record {'courier_id': 12, 'courier_type': 'car', 'regions': [12, 22, 23, 33]}
serializer.is_valid False
serializer.error {'regions': [{'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int.', code='invalid')]},`
it's like - i can't validate data from field "regions"

Comment: How i can change validate regions field as  a list positive integer field